# Android integrating with Zebra Symbol Technologies, Inc.:EMDK 3.0 (API 16):16

Tags: android, zebra-printers, motorola-emdk

I have imported a project and trying to build it. This project uses Zebra library. I can see that there is a module named `EMDK` which has a `build.gradle`.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Symbol Technologies, Inc.:EMDK 3.0 (API 16):16'
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':common')
}
```

In my app `build.gradle` the dependencies are given as:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'], exclude: ['com.symbol.emdk.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'

    provided files('./libs/com.symbol.emdk.jar')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
```

When I try to build I am getting this error in `../Library/Android/sdk`:

> failed to find target with hash string 'Symbol Technologies, Inc.:EMDK 3.0 (API 16):16

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the Symbol Technologies add-ons in your SDK add-ons folder?

You are also mixing two ways to include the jar, you do not need to specify both the `CompileSDKVersion` as the symbol add-on AND also provide the jar in your gradle. Personally I prefer just doing the latter and here is an example from [**one of my projects**](https://github.com/darryncampbell/WakeLock_WifiLock_Exerciser/blob/master/WakeLock_WifiLock_Exerciser/app/build.gradle#L33):

```
def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
compileOnly fileTree(include: ['com.symbol.emdk.jar'], dir: sdkDir+'/add-ons/addon-symbol_emdk-symbol-23/libs/')
```

I do not think it is a good idea to put the jar in the `/libs/` directory, doesn't Android Studio treat that specially and compile it in even though you have said 'provided files'... I'm not sure on that, but I would recommend just reading it from the add-ons directory as in my project's example.